# How to wrap texture coordinates manually?

Tags: c++, filter, textures, hlsl

I am using C++ and HLSL and need to have my texture coordinates wrap so that the texture is tiled across a triangle.

After the coordinates are "wrapped" into 0-1 range they will be rotated, so I can't simply use the texture sampler AddressU and AddressV properties set to wrap, because they need to be wrapped and THEN rotated, so it can't be done inside the sampler.

The solution here is simple, just use the fractional part of the texture coordinate and it will wrap.

Here is an example of a pixel shader that will tile the texture 36 times (`6 * 6`):

```
input.tex *= 6.0f; //number of times to tile ^ 2
input.tex = frac(input.tex); //wraps texCoords to 0-1 range
return shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);
```

This does tile the texture, but can create a problem at the boarder where the texture wraps. The tiles have to divide evenly into the space they are being displayed on or it creates a seam where the boarders meet. My square that the texture is drawn to is 800x600 pixels, so tiling by 5 will divide evenly but 6 will not and will cause seams along the Y axis.

I have tried using the modulus operator `input.tex = input.tex % 1` to wrap the coordinates but I get the exact same results. I have also tried changing the texture filtering method and the AddressU and AddressV properties along with countless different methods of debugging.

I had some luck using this code. If the `x` coordinate is too high it gets set to 0, and if it is too low it gets set to 1.

```
input.tex *= 6.0f;
input.tex = frac(input.tex);
if (input.tex.x > 0.999f) input.tex.x = 0;
if (input.tex.x < 0.001f) input.tex.x = 1;
return shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);
```

This only fixes the problem in certain spots though, so it is definitely not a solution.

Here is a picture that shows a texture (left) and what it looks like when wrapped manually (right). You can see that not everywhere that the boarders touch has this error.

[image]

I have also tried not changing the texture coordinates to 0-1 range and rotating them around the center of each tile instead of (0.5, 0.5) but I get identical results. Also my texture coordinates are completely independent of the vertices and are calculated inside the pixel shader.

Anything I have seen relating to this issue has to do with having a high value at one pixel and then a low value at the next, for example u = 0.95 and the next pixel u = 0.03, which causes it to interpolate backwards across the texture. But when I rotate my texture coordinates nothing changes at all. Even when each tile has a random rotation applied to it. In this case the edges have all sorts of different values bordering each other, not just a high value on the left side and a low value on the right side, but the area where the seam occurs never changes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MuertoExcobito said the main problem is that at the borders the texture coordinate jumps from 1 to 0 in a single pixel. Semantically it is right to say that the entire texture gets averaged in this pixel, but it is not caused by interpolating the texture from 1 to 0 in this pixel. The real reason is the mipmapping.

For your texture there are mipmaps generated as you are loading it. This means the texture get multiple mipmap levels which are all half sized in respect to the before.

[image]

If a texture becomes distorted sampling of the highest level would lead to oversampling (pointfiltering like artifacts). To fight oversampling a texture lookup chooses the appropriate mipmaplevel dependent on the changes of the texture coordinate in screen space. In your case the borders are a very high change in a small place, which is leading to use the lowest mipmap possible (which is as you see a small red dot, which is the reason for the red border).

Returning to your problem, you should take control over the mipmapping by using the texture lookup method `SampleGrad` ([Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb509698%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). To get the current changes of the texture coordinate of your pixel you can use the intrinsic methods `ddx` and `ddy`. They return for a arbitary variable in your shader, how it changes locally to adjacent pixels (the correct explaination would go to deep for this topic). So using following code shouldn't change anything, because it should be semantically identical:

```
input.tex *= 6.0f; //number of times to tile ^ 2
input.tex = frac(input.tex); //wraps texCoords to 0-1 range
float2 xchange = ddx(input.tex);
float2 ychange = ddy(input.tex);
return shaderTexture.SampleGrad(SampleType, input.tex, xchange, ychange);
```

Now you can apply your code which prevents big changes in xchange and ychange to force the graphic device to use a higher mipmap. This should remove you artifacts.

If your texture doesn't need mipmapping, because you are rendering the texture screen aligned and the texture size doesn't lead to oversampling, you can use the simpler alternative `sampleLevel` ([Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) There you can pass a parameter, which picks a specific mipmap, which you can determine by yourself.

Comment: I had kept thinking I wish there was a way to find out the change between pixels. This worked perfect and also keeping the mipmap level at a constant 0 worked so I believe you are correct that it is a mipmapping issue. Much thanks!

Comment: I added an answer that shows exactly how I implemented this

Answer (score 1):

The code here is causing the sampling the entire texture in the span of a single pixel. For example, for two adjacent pixels at the seam, one 'u' sample could be `1.0-eps`, the next sample would be `0.0+eps`, where `eps` is a number smaller than the width of a texel. When the output pixels are interpolated, you will interpolate from 1.0 .. 0.0, sampling the entire texture between those two samples. The averaging of the entire texture causes the 'greyness', even though your input texture doesn't actually contain any pixels that are exactly grey.

If you require to rotate the texture coordinates within each range (eg. 0..1, 1..2 are rotated independently), there are a few ways this could be solved. First, you could change the interpolation from linear to point, which will avoid the interpolation between texels. However, if you require bilinear interpolation, this might not be acceptable. In that case, you could construct a 'grid' mesh, and map the input texture 0..1 across each tile, with the tiles texture coordinates rotated independently in the shader.

Another possible solution, would be to transform the coordinates to 0..1 space, perform the rotation, and then translate them back into their original space. For example, you would do:

```
// pseudo-code:
int2 whole;
input.tex = modf(input.tex, whole);
input.tex = Rotate(input.tex); // do whatever rotation is needed
input.tex += whole;
```

This would ensure that the wrapping does not have any discontinuities. Alternatively, you could have your rotation code take into account non-unity space texture coordinates.

Comment: Yes each tile gets rotated independently by a random amount. I really need bilinear interpolation to keep quality. I can see how using a grid mesh would solve this problem but it wouldn't work for my purpose. My texture coordinates are independent of the vertex locations and are calculated in the PS. My algorithm tiles a texture over a mesh and rotates each tile randomly and morphs smoothly between one square to the next to basically create an infinite seamless texture that isn't very noticeably tiled. It works beautifully aside from the one issue.

Comment: Thank you for your post and you understood my question perfectly. I think there is a way to keep the u,v coordinates from jumping like this without adding vertices but it might take some heavy thinking.

Comment: Added another possible solution, which would allow you to keep bilerp, and not need to create a grid mesh.

Comment: I tried to add the whole integer part back on after rotation but unfortunately got the same results. I updated my question at the bottom to include this and to include my code for rotation. I'm not quite sure what is meant by "non-unity space texture coordinates"

Comment: Ok I think I know what you mean and I think it will work too. I will have to test it out once I get back home. I could do the rotation on the coordinates without putting them in 0-1 range and just have the center of rotation be the center of the tile instead of (0.5, 0.5)

Comment: Ok doing that didn't work either. I have now tried probably 20 different methods that will tile the texture but all produce some sort of major artifact =(

Answer (score 0):

Gnietschow posted the answer to this question but I am going to add an answer that shows exactly how I used the answer.
I'm actually not even sure why this works I just know it does even with other multiples of tiling, various textures, and random rotation.

```
input.tex *= 6.0f; //number of times to tile ^ 2
input.tex = frac(input.tex); //wraps texCoords to 0-1 range
float2 xchange = ddx(input.tex);
float2 ychange = ddy(input.tex);
if ((xchange.x < 0)) xchange = float2(0, 0);
if ((ychange.y < 0)) ychange = float2(0, 0);
return shaderTexture.SampleGrad(SampleType, input.tex, xchange, ychange);
```

if you don't need mipmapping at all, this other method Gniet mentioned works fine too

```
input.tex *= 6.0f; //number of times to tile ^ 2
input.tex = frac(input.tex); //wraps texCoords to 0-1 range
return shaderTexture.SampleLevel(SampleType, input.tex, 0);
```